# Users credentials and syncing from third party with WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api, password, authentication

I am trying to build a web store for a client who has already had a mobile app. 
the mobile app team would like to sync user's password as they update it both on the mobile app and the web store.

Also, they would like to authenticate users password either with user ID or email agains the webs store from the mobile app with some sort of API.

I am trying to figure out how to do these with WordPress REST API and WooCommerce REST API, or perhaps WordPress built-in auth.. but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

What would be the best approach to this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to the API and authentication.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wp-api. Its really easy and best. The documentation is also very clear and vast. Its provide a small plugin which can do everything you want.
http://wp-api.org/